# Executing a method on a object without casting it

Tags: java, introspection

I think this should be possible but I have a scenario where I'm executing a method which returns an object.

```
authentication.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

[ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/OAuth2Authentication.html)

This returns an object which at runtime is cast to my custom object, however if I want to play around with the principal, I need to cast this. I want to approach this in a generic way and extra the id from this object. I want to simply be able to call

```
principle.getId();
```

As the principle object will be a custom object of mine I can ensure that this method is always there. How can I call this in a generic way that will allow future objects to this as long as they contain the method I am calling

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `interface`, which essentially defines a set of functionalities that a `class` which implements that specific interface must obey to.

This is basically done by declaraing what you want to be able to call on your custom objects, eg:

```
interface Idable
{
  public int getId();
}
```

Now you can state that your custom object implements that interface, and the compile will force you to override the method, or declare the class as `abstract`:

```
class CustomObject implements Idable
{
  public int getId() {
    return whatever;
  }
}
```

Now you don't need to know anything more about your custom object, knowing that implements the interface is enough:

```
Idable idable = (Idable)authentication.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal();
idable.getId();
```

Of course this requires you to be able to interact which the returned object, otherwise you will be forced to use reflection and lose type safety:

```
Object obj = authentication.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal();

try {
  obj.getClass().getMethod("getId").invoke(obj);
}
```

Comment: I was looking for `obj.getClass().getMethod("getId").invoke(obj)` for so long, you have no idea! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. The return type is not `Object` though, it's a instance of `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication`.

Sut since that interface does not declare a `getID()` method, you have to continue to cast the return value to your own type.